# How to improve acoustics of a 16 meter square garage on a budget?

Tags: acoustics

I'll be renting a garage now for practice.
It will be used for several bands.

The garage size is 16 square meters and it doesn't matter if it's loud outside (these garages are pretty far from the buildings so nobody cares).

I really don't know anything about handling sound in a garage for a band, and I hope you guys could give me a few tips/what to do. We just aim for the best sound we can get for as lower price possible. Like using sponges/glass wool/egg boxes, no leather and expensive materials like that. For now.

The room is quite long, a bit tight. It's 5,32 m long, 2.87 m wide, and 2.19m high.
The drums will probably be on the back of the room - opposing the door.
I'll check the sound tommorow, and I'll update this.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Are you looking to sound proof or to improve the acoustic properties of the room?  They are completely different things.

Comment: (editing..) improve acoustics then I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not as easy (probably not even possible) over the Internet.  Modifying the sound of a room is rather complex and requires knowing what the current sound and shape of the room is, what the dimensions are, what materials it is made of, what shape it is.  What objects are in the room, where the sounds will originate within the room, where the listeners will be, etc, etc.  In general, if you have echo, sound dampening material will work.  Thick blankets on the wall is a really cheap option.

Comment: Have you checked out [this](http://avp.stackexchange.com/q/223/2569) question?  Some basic ideas for deadening a live room.

Comment: Thanks @Josh I'll check that out.

AJHenderson I'll edit my question for you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: absorption. Carpets on the floor, drapes/blankets on the wall. Then bass traps in the corner. If you are handy that might be a fun project.

**Please use hearing protection!** It's going to get loud in there.